# parse integer with javascript using parseInt and a radix

Tags: javascript

I am doing an online test and it asks me to write basic javascript code.

It asks me to parse a numberic string and convert it to a number of a different base. It needs me to return -1 if for whatever reason the conversion cannot be done.

I have written this:

```
function convert(strNumber, radix) {
     var result = parseInt(strNumber, radix);
     if(isNaN(result))
     {return -1;}
     return result;
}
```

Then it runs my code through various tests and all pass. Except one.

Apparently `convert("ASD", 15)` should be invalid according to the test and it expects it to be -1.
But Javascript happily converts it to number 10

I tried various things such as to add a try{}catch{} block and other things, but javascript never complains about converting "ASD" to base 15.

Is the test wrong, or is `parseInt` wrong?

By the way strNumber can be any base under 36.
So for instance:

```
convert("Z", 36) is 35
```

Comment: parseInt will parse values up to the point it fails. EG `parseInt("10px", 10)` is `10`. In this case `A` is 10 and `S` is invalid

Comment: _"It asks me to parse a numberic string and convert it to a number"_ `if (isNaN("ASD")) return -1` or `if(!/\d/.test("ASD")) return -1`

Comment: But "ASD" is a valid number in bases over 29+

Comment: @Nick The requirement is not to only checking for digit characters `[0-9]`?

Comment: No it's for all bases. So for example convert("AF", 16) returns 175 which is correct

Comment: _"Apparently `convert("ASD", 15)` should be invalid"_ Then why should `"ASD"` be invalid?

Comment: I think I am starting to understand. radix 15 means the letters allowed are A, B, C, D, E. How can the javascript be changed to catch that? That will be the correct answer in my case

Comment: `if (/[A-E]/.test(strNumber)) { // do stuff } else { return -1 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in the comment, parseInt will convert up to the point where it fails. So "A" is valid in that radix and "S" is not. So you would need to add a check.

```
var nums = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".substr(0, radix)
var re = new RegExp("^[" + nums + "]+$","i")
if (!re.test(strNumber)) {
   return -1
}
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks!!

Comment: Radix value should be no more then 36. If bigger then this code will break.

Answer (score 1):

`parseInt` is behaving normally and is converting the letter `A` into 10 in base 15 (similar to how hex uses `A` for the number 10). The `S` and `D` are discarded, as `parseInt` accepts this type of malformed input.

From [the `parseInt` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

> If `parseInt` encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and returns the integer value parsed up to that point.

Comment: Can we check which letters are allowed based on the radix? That will be the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

As per official [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) the `parseInt` function behaves as following

> For radices above 10, the letters of the alphabet indicate numerals
>   greater than 9. For example, for hexadecimal numbers (base 16), A
>   through F are used.

and

> If parseInt encounters a character that is not a numeral in the
>   specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and
>   returns the integer value parsed up to that point.

Thus to prevent invalid arguments from being parsed they have to be validated first

```js
  function convert(strNumber, radix) {
 if (isValidRadix(radix) && isValidInteger(strNumber, radix))
   return parseInt(strNumber, radix);
  
 return -1;
}

function isValidInteger(str, radix) {
  var letters = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'].slice(0,radix);
  str = str.toUpperCase();
  for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
    var s = str.charAt(i);
    if (letters.indexOf(s) == -1) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function isValidRadix(radix) {
  // 16 up to HEX system
  return radix > 0 && radix <= 16;
}
 
console.log(convert("ASD", 15));
console.log(parseInt("ASD", 15));
console.log(convert("AAA", 15));
```

Comment: But "AAA" is valid with base 15. Your code fails the test.

Comment: You are right, this validation is no applicable for the none 10-base system, I am not sure if there is a function for it in JavaScript. In worst case you can define it yourself.

Comment: I have added a function to validate string per radix

Comment: You should probably should include up to 36 (max for parseInt)

Comment: No, it should be enough as it handles any radix up to HEX

Comment: Yes, but parseInt goes to radix of 36, so it should 0-9 and A-Z `parseInt("Z", 36)`